# Converting PHP response string to JSON in Android, always says JSON string is Malformed

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to send data from MSSQL table on server to Android app via PHP.  I am using Volley to send the request for data.

The issue is that no matter what I try, Android says the returned JSON encoded string is "Malformed".

I have put the returned JSON string "response" into online JSON decoders and it displays perfectly, yet Andoid says: "Syntax error, malformed JSON{"data":[{"claimNumber":"f265e5e.....}]".

However, if I hardcode a copy and paste of the returned "response" string into a variable "input" in the Android
response function, it works perfectly.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response); ** Fails - Android says Malformed.
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(input);  ** Android uses it with no issues.
```

The following is the method in Android used to receive the PHP response. Have included Log outputs of both the "response" string and
the manually entered "input" string.  They are identical, yet Android won't use the actual "response" string.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
   if (response.equals("failed")) {
       Log.d("failed", "failed");
       callback.onResponse(null);
       return;
   }
    try {
// Android sees the response returned from the PHP function as always Malformed.
    Log.d("response", response);  
    D/response:  - Syntax error, malformed JSON {"data":[{"claimNumber":"f265e5e6513070abd1f711232cfd3a491075f15bc9714cf723e373f02e71a214","xlsLine":"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","markerColor":"0","edited":"0"}]}

// If I copy the returned "response" string manually into a variable "input", Android says it's fine.
    String input = "{\"data\":[{\"claimNumber\":\"f265e5e6513070abd1f711232cfd3a491075f15bc9714cf723e373f02e71a214\",\"xlsLine\":\"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\",\"markerColor\":\"0\",\"edited\":\"0\"}]}";

// Log showing Androids interpretation of the manually entered "input" string
// It matches the "response" string exactly yet "response" string fails.

    Log.d("input", input);  
    D/input: {"data":[{"claimNumber":"f265e5e6513070abd1f711232cfd3a491075f15bc9714cf723e373f02e71a214","xlsLine":"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","markerColor":"0","edited":"0"}]}

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(input);
        jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("data");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// GSON print of JSON Object from the manually entered "input" variable.
I/System.out: {
            "nameValuePairs": {
              "data": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "nameValuePairs": {
                      "claimNumber": "f265e5e6513070abd1f711232cfd3a491075f15bc9714cf723e373f02e71a214",
                      "xlsLine": "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",
                      "markerColor": "0",
                      "edited": "0"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
```

Have tried php output with and without slashes.  No change... still malformed.
Have tried stripping non-standard chars.  There are none.
Have forced charset "UTF-8".  No difference.
Have searched and tried every conceivable solution for this on Google.  Nothing works.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.  Totally confused on why Android can't use the returned Json string,
but can use it if you manually take the same string and put it in a variable in the code directly.

Can someone tell me if this is a known bug, if the JSON really is malformed or if something else comes to mind?

Thank you

EDIT

Here is the PHP that creates the json to return to Android.

```
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn3, $tsql1, $params, $options); 
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt2);
if ($row_count === false) {
    echo("failed");
} else {
    while( $userClaims = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $claimNum = $userClaims['ClaimNumber'];
        $xls = $userClaims['XLS'];
        $color = $userClaims['Color'];
        $edited = "0";
            $keyvals = (object) array("claimNumber" => $claimNum, "xlsLine" => $xls, "markerColor" => $color, "edited" => $edited);
            array_push($response,$keyvals);
    }

    $encoded = json_encode(array('data' => $response));
```

EDIT 2

The following is the complete php section of code that creates the json return string.  The array is initialized at the top.  Have written the php json string to a text file on server and copied the text to a json checker and it works fine.

```
     $response = array();
        $i = 0;
        $param1 = $token;
        $params = array( &$param1);
        $tsql1 = "SELECT * FROM Claims WHERE Token = ? AND DeletionFlag = 0";
        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
        $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn3, $tsql1, $params, $options); 
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt2);
        if ($row_count === false) {
            echo("failed");
        } else {
            while( $userClaims = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $claimNum = $userClaims['ClaimNumber'];
                $xls = $userClaims['XLS'];
                $color = $userClaims['Color'];
                $edited = "0";
                    $keyvals = (object) array("claimNumber" => $claimNum, "xlsLine" => $xls, "markerColor" => $color, "edited" => $edited);
                    array_push($response,$keyvals);
            }
            $encoded = json_encode(array('data' => $response));
            echo $encoded;
        }
sqlsrv_close($conn3);
```

Comment: Where is the code that generates the json?

Comment: try compare the length() of response string and input string: `Log.d("lengths","res: "+response.length()+", input: "+input.length());` there might be unreadable characters e.g. "\0"

Comment: Added the php code that generates json in above EDIT.  Tried the test for lengths got: lengths: res: 936, input: 905.  Can't find any non-standard chars though.  Any ideas on how to find and remove them?  Thanks.

Comment: The stack trace sometimes helps in showing where in the json parser it had issues.  Also the exception should have a message which should also amplify the error.  Worst case use the debugger to look at the bytes of the 'response' variable.

Comment: OK - you may not like this but...the android 'response' variable actually has the string 'Syntax error, malformed JSON {"data....' which is a total of 936 characters.  So this points to the php side producing the error and returning it which naturally is not json.  So this becomes a php-debugging case and one thing to verify is '$response' an empty array initially - can't tell with listing.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy.  Added the full php section above in EDIT 2.  Array is initialized at top of section.

Comment: Very strange - so json_encode returns valid JSON or FALSE so seems unlikely that is the issue.  (One technique is to use the URL of the volley request and post it into a browser and see response).  There must be _something_ else between the PHP output and the android code posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Andy.  I finally figured it out.  I found a line of code in the php file that was out of place.  It was trying to json_decode an empty string.  This is what was generating the extra 36 chars about the malformed string in my actual response.  Once I moved it to the correct place, everything started working beautifully.  Should have known better, most likely a blasted copy/paste error.  Should teach me not to be lazy and actually type ALL my code.  Thanks, again!!